# xamarin компоновка элементов

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Пытаюсь освоить xamarin как было бы грамотнее реализовать расположение компонентов на activity так как на картинке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
примечание компоненты генерируются динамически
На картинке один так скажем "блок", но их может быть несколько. Хотелось бы что бы они располагались один под другим, или же каким то образом засунуть (картинку, название картинки, текст) на один компонент скажем ImageButton?

Answer (score 0):

1) Создаете RecyclerView.

2) Создаете данную компоновку любым способом которым хотите, хоть через Linearlayout, RelativeLayout....

3) по событию, добавляете 2 в 1